# Clarification on SQL Server connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, connection-string, web-deployment

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to write my web app using SQL Server 2012 backend. This is my connection string which works fine.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add
        name="UserDetails"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UserDetails.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=30;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But while deploying as Web deploy package, I could generate .zip and deploy.cmd and setparameters.xml/SourceManifest.xml file gets generated successfully. As guided in deploy-readme.txt, I executed the below command which was successful.

```
App.deploy.cmd /T /L -allowUntrusted /M:http://localhost/MSDeployAgentService
```

I tried to replace /T with /Y and here is where I get the error as below.

**ERROR**

> Error Code: ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT
>   More Information: Failed to create type 'Microsot.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT.
>   Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: The connection string argument AttachDBFilename is not supported

AttachDBFilename was proposed in MSDN. I exactly don't understand the reason for this error.

I tried not to include the database while publishing and the above command succeeded and I was able to launch the application hosted. However, SQL Server connection fails at later point. So, I could figure out that I have got some issue with my connection string but I am stuck here for a week. You suggestions will be really helpful and please assist me if I have missed anything.

Comment: The `AttachDbFileName=` setting *only* works with SQL Server **Express** editions - so if your SQL Server where you deploy to is a Standard, Web or Enterprise edition, you **cannot** use the `AttachDbFileName=` part in your connection string - you need to create the database **on the server** (in SQL Server Management Studio) and then create the necessary db objects using SQL scripts

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have removed AttachDbFilename and changed the data source from localdb to the actual DB on the server.